# Construct pandas dataframe from a .fits file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, astropy

I have a .fits file that contains data.

I would like to construct a pandas dataframe from this particular file but I don't know how to do it.

```
data = fits.open('datafile')
data.info
```

gives:

```
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU       6   (12, 250000)   float64
```

and:

```
data[0].data.shape
```

gives:

```
(250000, 12)
```

Comment: impossible to answer unless you include a sample of this file and what the desired result should look like

Comment: It is a dataset with 250 000 rows that represent people, and 12 features which represent their characteristics. 

So I need a simple 250000x12 dataframe

Comment: So have you tried `df = pd.read_csv('datafile')`?

Comment: Yes. I get a UnicodeDecode error.

Comment: FITS is a mixed text and binary file format used primarily in astronomy. read_csv has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to what you have in your question and the astropy docs (http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/), it looks like you just need to do:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import pandas
with fits.open('datafile') as data:
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data[0].data)
```

Edit:
I don't have much experience we astropy, but other have mentioned that you can read the fits files into a `Table` object, which has a `to_pandas()` method:

```
from astropy.table import Table
dat = Table.read('datafile', format='fits')
df = dat.to_pandas()
```

Might be worth investigating.

http://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/table/pandas.html

Comment: Just a minor comment here: You should close the file if you explicitly `open` it, or use the contextmanager: `with fits.open('datafile') as data:` so you don't leave open file handles flapping around.

Answer (score 4):

Note: the second option with Table is better for most cases, since the way FITS files store data is big-endian, which can cause problems when reading into a DataFrame object which is little-endian. See https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/1156