# Conversion FIT file at CSV file

Tags: python, csv, file-conversion, garmin

How can I convert a FIT file (Garmim) at CSV file? I built this structure and some of the data is wrong, how can I fix it?

```
import fitparse
import pandas as pd

fitfile = fitparse.FitFile("#MyPath")
fitfile.parse()
all_data = []
for record in fitfile.get_messages('record'):
 record_dict = {'timestamp': record.get_value('timestamp')}
 for record_data in record:
     if record_data.units:
         record_dict[record_data.name] = f"{record_data.value} {record_data.units}"
     else:
         record_dict[record_data.name] = record_data.value
 all_data.append(record_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct pandas dataframe from a .fits file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111872/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-a-fits-file)

Comment: We can't see your input file, or your output file, so it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: Numbers at the answer are wrong. My file is .FIT, not .FITS